# Use HTMLWebpackPlugin with an EJS file

Tags: webpack, webpack-html-loader

I want to use the HTMLWebpackPlugin to take my `index.ejs` template file, insert my bundled assets, and output a final `index.ejs` file.

This example has a EJS variable `<%= API_URL %>`, but webpack is interpreting it.

How can I stop webpack from substituting the variable?

**Starting "template":**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Monitor</title>
    <script>
      window.config = {
        API_URL: "<%= API_URL %>"
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**When you try to run webpack:**

`ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: API_URL is not defined`

**Desired result index.ejs: (has bundled assets and EJS var)**

Monitor
    
      window.config = {
       API_URL: "<%= API_URL %>"
      }

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      // CSS is imported in app.js.
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
        loader: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      })
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        'API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL)
      }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.ejs',
      inject: true
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a really bad hacky solution, and I hope someone else has a real answer / understanding of how to do this.

In your template file (index.ejs), do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Monitor</title>
    <script>
      window.config = {
        API_URL: "<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.API_URL_TEMPLATE_VAR %>"
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your webpack config, do this (the relevant part is the new HtmlWebpackPlugin where I define a variable.:

```
plugins: [
    // Define environment variables that are accessible inside of app javascript.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    }),
    // Adds bundled file links to the index.html
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // The input file name
      template: 'src/index.prod.ejs',
      // Injects scripts into the <body>
      inject: true,
      // This is so hacky. I inject a string so the built .ejs file has this template var. Lets us set api_url when server is started instead of at bundle time.
      API_URL_TEMPLATE_VAR: '<%= process.env.API_URL %>',
      // The output file name
      filename: 'index.ejs'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
  ],
```

Because I defined `API_URL_TEMPLATE_VAR`, when html-webpack-plugin evaluates it, it will print out `<%= process.env.API_URL %>` into the final template.

Hacky, but works.  Not accepting my own answer / waiting for a better answer.

Comment: Upvoted because, although hacky, seems like the only solution which answers this question and solves a problem. I searched a lot and this is the only answer I could find

Comment: This will work, but what about `if` in the `ejs`?
You will have to put all the login in the `webpack.config.js`...

Comment: For me, all I needed was `filename: 'index.ejs'` and then I loaded it using `raw-loader`, which causes Webpack to load the file as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and adding a quote (") to the definition of the variable solved it:

In your case:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    'API_URL': '"' + JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL) + '"'
  }
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTMLWebpackPlugin uses lodash.template for this and it should be possible though not very easy to change the default delimiter for it to something like `<?` so you can use the `<%` delimiter for the frontend. However if you're using the ejs package for the frontend it would be a lot easier to change the delimiter there and keep the normal one for webpack.

*ejs:*

```
<div>
  <%=SOME_WEBPACK_VAR%>
  <br />
  <?=SOME_EJS_VAR%>
</div>
```

*javascript:*

```
ejs.render(yourHtml, {SOME_EJS_VAR: 'foo'}, {delimiter: '?'});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand EJS, your problem would be solved by using `<%%=` as explained in the [EJS docs](https://ejs.co/#docs), so replacing your code by:
`API_URL: "<%%= API_URL %>"`,

Answer (score -1):

If you want Webpack to ignore your file from the build you can prepend [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) in front of the file path like this:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: true,
    filename: "index.ejs",
    template: "!!raw-loader!" + 'src/index.ejs',
}),
```

And in case you want to inject variables into your template directly from Webpack you can use a dependency called `react-dev-utils`, which has a very handy plugin for this:

```
new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, {
   PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl,
  // You can pass any key-value pairs, this was just an example.
  // WHATEVER: 42 will replace %WHATEVER% with 42 in index.html.
}),
```

Haven't tried with an ejs template myself but I see no reason that it shouldn't work.